# ShareLink with computed text

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to share a formatted version of an array of structs.

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    ShareLink(item: observedObject.toFormattedString())
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

However, I get a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xab849c4e0c41cdb0)` when launching the app and the array (stored with @AppStorage) isn't empty.

[image: format function]

Is there a way to accomplish the equivalent of passing a function to `ShareLink` that only gets called when the Share button is pressed?

```swift
ShareLink(item: {
   observedObject.toFormattedString()
})
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72035626/20898396) code but nothing happens. (edit: it works if the sheet isn't in a toolbar)

Edit: The issue is with `String(format: "%s %s %s", a, b, c)`, there are no crashes if I use `"\(a) \(b) \(c)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNKnChO5aPc) video and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71010586/20898396) answer:

```
Button {
    share(text: "Test")
} label: {
    Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
```

```
func share(text: String){
    let viewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)

    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true)
    
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        viewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = window
        viewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.1 , y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 1.3, width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

I think that the iPad crashes because it doesn't know where to place the share box. There must be a better way to position it.